# Grails RabbitMQ ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException

Tags: grails, plugins, rabbitmq

i am trying to use the RabbitMQ plugin and whatever i do i am getting
a org.springframework.amqp.ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException:
Recovered
message forces ack (if ack mode requires it):...

I am sending AMQP messages using a pure Spring app using the AMQP
template and trying to handle the messages in a Grails 2.0.3 app. Is
there something that i am missing?
What can i do to get rid of this errors?

Kind Regards,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. But then I realised I named my handleMessage method incorrectly. My listener class (I'm only learning!) now looks like this, and doesn't show the ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException.

```
class ListenerService {

static rabbitQueue = 'sub'
    def handleMessage(message) {
        println "Message received"
    }
 }
```